# how to extract using inner join if table have Repetitive values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

what will be query for inner join in sql server

```
table1
|---------|------------|-------------|------|
|object_id| object_name|parent_object|type  | 
|---------|------------|-------------|------|
|885      | unique1    |245          |UQ    |
|901      |unique2     |245          |UQ    |
|---------|------------|-------------|------|

 table2
    |---------|------------|-------------|
    |object_id| object_name|is_unique_constraint|
    |---------|------------|-------------|
    |245      | unique1    |1            |
    |245      |unique2     |1            |
    |---------|------------|-------------|
```

Output Required

```
|---------|------------|-------------|-------|-------------------|
|object_id| object_name|parent_object|type   |isuniqueconstraint |
|---------|------------|-------------|-------|-------------------|
|885      | unique1    |245          |UQ     |1                  |
|901      |unique2     |245          |UQ     |1                  |
|---------|------------|-------------|-------|-------------------|
```

while writing my query i am getting repetative result

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.parent_object_id = table2.object_id
WHERE type = 'UQ'
    AND is_unique_constraint = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to include the `object_name` in the `join` condition:

```
select . . .
from table1 inner join
     table2
     on table1.parent_object_id = table2.object_id and
        table1.object_name = table2.object_name
where type = 'UQ' and is_unique_constraint = 1;
```